# Asynchronous Scheduling in Java using Quartz

Tags: java, asynchronous, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I need a mechanism for implementing asynchronous job scheduling in Java and was looking at the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), but it seems that it does not offer the necessary functionality.

More specifically, my application, which runs across different nodes, has a web-based UI, via which users schedule several different jobs. When a job is completed (sometime in the future), it should report back to the UI, so that the user is informed of its status. Until then, the user should have the option of editing or cancelling a scheduled job.

An implementation approach would be to have a Scheduler thread running constantly in the background in one of the nodes and collecting JobDetail definitions for job execution.

In any case, there are two the questions (applicable for either a single-node or multi-node scenario):

1. Does Quartz allow a modification or a cancellation of an already scheduled job?
2. How can a "callback" mechanism be implemented so that a job execution result is reported back to the UI?

Any code examples, or pointers, are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Does Quartz allow a modification or a cancellation of an already scheduled job?

You can "unschedule" a job:

```
scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey("trigger1", "group1"));
```

Or delete a job:

```
scheduler.deleteJob(jobKey("job1", "group1"));
```

As described in the docs:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UnscheduleJob

Note, the main difference between the two is unscheduleing a job removes the given trigger, while deleting the job removes all triggers to the given job.

1. How can a "callback" mechanism be implemented so that a job execution result is reported back to the UI?

Typically, in the web world, you will poll the web server for changes.  Depending upon your web framework, there may be a component available (Push, Pull, Poll?) that makes this easy.  Also, what you will need to do is store some state about your job on the server.  Once the job finishes you may update a value in the database or possibly in memory.  This, in turn, would be picked up by the polling and displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of @johncarl with Quarz also have this

1. handle event's before and after the excution [implementing SchedulerListener interface](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-08)
2. Groups your jobs
3. Support with Enterprise Edition
4. Most important the cron expressions [here's the documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)